# Connection between SQL Server 2014 and Oracle 12c

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2014, oracle-12c

I have to server:

1.`Server_A` with *Oracle 12c*

2.`Server_B` with *SQL Server 2014*

I want these servers see each other, though I can SELECT anything I want in `Server_A` from `Server_B` and vice versa.

I only want SELECT queries (no possibility to run INSERT, UPDATE, INSERT queries), and also if possible EXECUTE any procedures.